# Ajax call to wcf service is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wcf

I have writter a webservice which is returning json string. I am trying to call this service from a html page. But the ajax call is not returning the desired result.

the code to call the service is as follows

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3292/examservice.svc/ExamQs"
}).then(function(data) {

   $('.question').append(data.Question);
   $('.answer').append(data.Answer1);
});
});
</script>

 <body>
    <div>
        <p class="question">The Question is </p>
        <p class="answer">The Answer is </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The output from the service is

```
[{"Answer1":"This is Answer1 of Question 1","Answer2":"This is Answer2 of Question 1","Answer3":"This is Answer3 of Question 1","Answer4":"This is Answer4 of Question 1","Correct":1,"Question":"This is the Question no 1"}]
```

Comment: the output (data) is an Array .. so `data[0].Question` etc

Comment: It works. Thank you @JaromandaX